# cloudinary-ios - Invalid Signature - GenerateCLDCryptoModule

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, cloudinary

I am using manual Cloudinary integration and is having this error during app store upload...

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The file at path [BucketListApp.app/Frameworks/Cloudinary.framework/GenerateCLDCryptoModule] is not properly signed

So far, I have tried many different code signing variants, tried to shift toward pods, downgraded to xcode 8 to add support for swift 2, tried to write code in swift, tried adding a bunch of workaround codes in podFile. But unfortunately I was not able even run Cloudinary SDK using any of the methods above.

The only method worked for me was the manual integration, it works well but only road block now is when I upload to app store from XCode I get this error.

[image: screen shot 2017-12-04 at 5 12 24 pm]

Comment: Please check if the _CodeSignature for this is deleted for the older one and new one is getting added, Also check the entitlements are reflecting the right details in the singed Payload binary folder after unzipping. Make sure the details of xml matches to the app.entitlements file.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary just published a Release Candidate for its iOS library - `2.0.4-rc1`. CLDCryptoModule is removed in this RC so you shouldn't face this issue.

Comment: will surely give it a try real soon and get back to you.